# blocking specific links with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a gallery I want to block certain thumbnails from expanding their original picture via lightbox.
The images don't have an ID, just a class. All of the links are read from a table in a database.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            if($('.product-image').attr('target', 'blockedpath')) {
                $('.product-image').click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                });
            }
        }); 


<li class="product">
            <div class="productInfo">
                <h3>@i.ToString()</h3>
                <a href="@Href("~/Images/2013/" + i.ToString() + ".jpg")" rel="lightbox" class="link">
                    <img class="product-image" src="@Href("~/Images/2013/Thumbnails/" + i.ToString() + ".jpg")" alt="foto" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
```

If I use this, all thumbnails get blocked. How can I prevent just the blocked pictures and avoid blocking the thumbnails.
Would it be possible, to save all images which should be blocked in an array and loop through that array to block those thumbnails?

Comment: You should use `data` attribute, not `target`.

Comment: By using this code actually you are forcefully setting `target` to `blockedpath` for all `.product-image'`

Comment: added html/Razer Markup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are first checking whether any images exist with `target = blockedpath`, then blocking **all** images.

You could use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Select elements with the product-images class, that also 
    // have a target attribute with a value equal to 'blockedpath'
    // Bind a click event to the matched elements
    $('.product-image[target="blockedpath"]').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: It somehow does not work. I'd like to post my Razer Markup, but the editor swallows it all except 1 line of c#-code. Every picture stay clickable

Comment: I was lazy and just implemented an if-clause with an foreach loop, iterating through all filenames to filter them out, before creating the mark up.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[target=blockedpath]').click(function( e ){
  e.preventDeault();
});
```

or the opposite:

```
$('.product-image').not('[target=blockedpath]').click(function(){
  alert('hi!');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/